# Why wouldn't a flex remoteobject be able to work within a custom component?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, jakarta-ee, blazeds

Please enlighten this flex noob.  I have a remoteobject within my main.mxml.  I can call a function on the service from an init() function on my main.mxml, and my java debugger triggers a breakpoint.  When I move the remoteobject declaration and function call into a custom component (that is declared within main.mxml), the remote function on java-side no longer gets called, no breakpoints triggered, no errors, silence.

How could this be?  No spelling errors, or anything like that.  What can I do to figure it out?

mxml code:

&#060 mx:RemoteObject id="myService"
    destination="remoteService"
    endpoint="${Application.application.home}/messagebroker/amf" &#062
&#060 /mx:RemoteObject &#062

function call is just 'myService.getlist();'

when I move it to a custom component, I import mx.core.Application; so the compiler doesn't yell

my child component: child.mxml

```
<mx:Panel xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init()" >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.Application;
            public function init():void {
                helloWorld.sayHello();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:RemoteObject id="helloWorld" destination="helloService" endpoint="$(Application.application.home}/messagebroker/amf" />

    <mx:Label text="{helloWorld.sayHello.lastResult}" />
</mx:Panel>
```

my main.mxml:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init()" xmlns:test="main.flex.*" >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var home:String;
            [Bindable]
            public var uName:String;
            public function init():void {
                //passed in by wrapper html
                home = Application.application.parameters.appHome;
                uName = Application.application.parameters.uName;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <test:child />
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: are you able to see if the function (on the flex side) that contains the service call is getting called?

Comment: yes, I set up alerts to pop up before and after the remoteobject service call, and they do.

Comment: do you think you could post more code?

Comment: added code... it all works fine if I copy paste the remote object into main and run sayhello from its init(), but the point is I need the child to handle it.

Comment: Flex creation timing:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/images/lifecycle_container.png

I'll just do my initialization in initialize instead of creationComplete for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child components are calling creationComplete before the parent (so home is null). A solution is to throw an event (like InitDataCompleted) from the parent after you read the data, and in the child components listen for this event (so don't rely on creationcomplete in the child).

However more important than that is how can you diagnose in future this kind of problems. A simple tool like a proxy (eg Charles) should help.

Comment: so, how do I use mxml declarations that rely on these values being set?  A colleague mentioned to use 'show' instead of creationcomplete, but I don't fully understand the timing.

Comment: One of the hardest part when learning Flex is to think asynchronously. In your case your operation (remote calls etc) should be done only when you are sure that the data is read. So the main application should throw an event after reading data and the child should listen for this event. When the event is received in the child it is safe to do your operations. 

And no, in your case I will not rely on components livecycle (like init and create)

Comment: so I would have to declare my remoteobjects in mxml (or AS), and then modify them in actionscript when the event is received, or is there a shortcut within flex already?

Comment: You don't need to modify them, because databinding "{}" will do that automatically. You need to execute the remote call only after you are sure that the initialization was changed.
If your application can grow larger I strongly recommend to take a look on some flex framework/patterns. A good framework is http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/

Answer (score 0):

For your endpoint value you've got

```
endpoint="$(Application.application.home}/messagebroker/amf"
```

Why are you using $( before Application.application... This should be a { as in:

```
endpoint="{Application.application.home}/messagebroker/amf"
```

Comment: oh, it's a typo, I manually typed it in to stackoverflow, fixed.  But I think it's a semantic issue because it compiles fine.